# Is it possible to use both DECODE and SELECT STATEMENT?

Tags: oracle, expression, decode, sql-loader

I'm new in using SQL Loader. is it possible to use both `DECODE` and `SELECT` statement? 
I'm trying to work this kind of logic and somewhat fail to solve it.

```
DUMMY_FIELD  "DECODE(A, NULL, (SELECT item_here FROM DB_TABLE WHERE column=:DUMMY_FIELD), A)",
```

I always get the Missing Expression Error. 
I tried inserting EXPRESSION with the select statement and with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to join the incoming data with other tables then I'd suggest using an external table instead of SQL*Loader, as external table's data can be joined to other data, aggregated, ordered and otherwise manipulated just as if it was selected from a normal table.

Also:

```
Decode(a, null, expr, a)
```

... would be better expressed as ...

```
Coalesce(a, expr)
```

Comment: i tried adding a function and use COALESCE(:a, func(:b, :c)) and still no luck. I'm having the error, "func": Invalid Identifier.

Comment: Looks like i forgot to add "Grant" execute access for the user role for the function i created, and now it is working fine and i used your COALESCE(:a, myFunc(:b,:c)). Thanks :)